# epoch_config must not be None

Tags: substrate-node-template, runtime

This is my [substrate-code](https://github.com/ganesh1233456/substrate-node). Running `cargo build --release` works fine but while starting node using `./target/release/node-template --dev`, I get this error.

`Thread 'main' panicked at 'epoch_config must not be None',`

Someone please help me what's going on here.

```rs
ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air default-substrate-node-template % ./target/release/node-template --dev                                 
2023-05-16 09:45:58 Substrate Node    
2023-05-16 09:45:58 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-unknown    
2023-05-16 09:45:58 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2023    
2023-05-16 09:45:58  Chain specification: Development    
2023-05-16 09:45:58   Node name: unknown-limit-2196    
2023-05-16 09:45:58  Role: AUTHORITY    
2023-05-16 09:45:58  Database: RocksDb at /var/folders/q3/d699hkpx49xfy236ph7sltr40000gn/T/substrateGQ0JqC/chains/dev/db/full    
2023-05-16 09:45:58 ⛓  Native runtime: node-268 (substrate-node-0.tx2.au10)    

====================

Version: 4.0.0-dev-unknown

   0: backtrace::capture::Backtrace::new
   1: sp_panic_handler::set::{{closure}}
   2: <alloc::boxed::Box<F,A> as core::ops::function::Fn<Args>>::call
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/alloc/src/boxed.rs:2002:9
      std::panicking::rust_panic_with_hook
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:692:13
   3: std::panicking::begin_panic_handler::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:579:13
   4: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_end_short_backtrace
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/sys_common/backtrace.rs:137:18
   5: rust_begin_unwind
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:575:5
   6: core::panicking::panic_fmt
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/core/src/panicking.rs:64:14
   7: core::panicking::panic_display
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/core/src/panicking.rs:136:5
   8: core::panicking::panic_str
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/core/src/panicking.rs:120:5
   9: core::option::expect_failed
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/core/src/option.rs:1923:5
  10: <pallet_babe::pallet::GenesisConfig as frame_support::traits::hooks::GenesisBuild<T>>::build
  11: std::thread::local::LocalKey<T>::with
  12: sp_state_machine::basic::BasicExternalities::execute_with_storage
  13: <node_template_runtime::GenesisConfig as sp_runtime::BuildStorage>::assimilate_storage
  14: <sc_chain_spec::chain_spec::ChainSpec<G,E> as sp_runtime::BuildStorage>::assimilate_storage
  15: sp_runtime::BuildStorage::build_storage
  16: sc_chain_spec::genesis::GenesisBlockBuilder<Block,B,E>::new
  17: sc_service::builder::new_full_parts
  18: node_template::service::new_partial
  19: node_template::service::new_full
  20: tokio::runtime::park::CachedParkThread::block_on
  21: tokio::runtime::scheduler::multi_thread::MultiThread::block_on
  22: tokio::runtime::runtime::Runtime::block_on
  23: node_template::command::run
  24: std::sys_common::backtrace::__rust_begin_short_backtrace
  25: std::rt::lang_start::{{closure}}
  26: core::ops::function::impls::<impl core::ops::function::FnOnce<A> for &F>::call_once
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/core/src/ops/function.rs:287:13
      std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
      std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
      std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
      std::rt::lang_start_internal::{{closure}}
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:48
      std::panicking::try::do_call
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:483:40
      std::panicking::try
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panicking.rs:447:19
      std::panic::catch_unwind
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/panic.rs:140:14
      std::rt::lang_start_internal
             at /rustc/574b64a97f52162f965bc201e47f0af8279ca65d/library/std/src/rt.rs:148:20
  27: _main


Thread 'main' panicked at 'epoch_config must not be None', /Users/ganesholi/.cargo/git/checkouts/substrate-7e08433d4c370a21/3bb3882/frame/babe/src/lib.rs:330

This is a bug. Please report it at:

        support.anonymous.an

ganesholi@Ganeshs-MacBook-Air default-substrate-node-template %
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like it said, `must not be None`.

Source: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/dd478bc60eb83a5f8f25aa65fdac2e519e9545ab/frame/babe/src/lib.rs#L329-L331

Soluation: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/dd478bc60eb83a5f8f25aa65fdac2e519e9545ab/bin/node/cli/src/chain_spec.rs#L344